# HTML file with Dojo refuses to work from my local machine

Tags: html, dojo, modal-dialog, alert

I am using some CDN links in a file copied directly from a dojo tutorial. I can't figure out why it won't work. There is supposed to be a dialog when you click the Show Me! button but the parts of the dialog are just visible on the page and the button does nothing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>

<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.4/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.4/dojo/dojo.js"
           data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>

<script>
 require(["dijit/Dialog", "dijit/form/TextBox", "dijit/form/Button"]);
</script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/Dialog" data-dojo-id="myDialog" title="Name and Address">
<table class="dijitDialogPaneContentArea">
    <tr>
        <td><label for="name">Name:</label></td>
        <td><input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" name="name" id="name"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="address">Address:</label></td>
        <td><input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" name="address" id="address">     </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div class="dijitDialogPaneActionBar">
    <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="submit" id="ok">OK</button>
    <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button" data-dojo-props="onClick:function(){myDialog.hide();}"
            id="cancel">Cancel</button>
</div>
 </div>

<button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button" onClick="myDialog.show();">
Show me!
</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you had a "http:" missing in the second CDN loading thingy. And then it seems that somehow the dijit dialog files aren't loading... ! You could load them manually **OR**
you could switch the version of dojo from 1.7.4 to 1.8 (i would advise that) by loading 1.8  files & then it should work. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>

<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8/dojo/dojo.js"
           data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>

<script>
 require(["dijit/Dialog", "dijit/form/TextBox", "dijit/form/Button"]);
</script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/Dialog" data-dojo-id="myDialog" title="Name and Address">
<table class="dijitDialogPaneContentArea">
    <tr>
        <td><label for="name">Name:</label></td>
        <td><input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" name="name" id="name"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="address">Address:</label></td>
        <td><input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" name="address" id="address">     </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div class="dijitDialogPaneActionBar">
    <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="submit" id="ok">OK</button>
    <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button" data-dojo-props="onClick:function(){myDialog.hide();}"
            id="cancel">Cancel</button>
</div>
 </div>

<button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button" onClick="myDialog.show();">
Show me!
</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You've always got to use a webserver even if you're viewing locally. It simply won't run from your local filesystem.

> Run your source code from a web server, not the file system, even if the web server is
>   running on your development machine. The browser's handling of HTTP requests from the local
>   file system are more restrictive than from a web server, even when it's running in the same
>   machine. For consistent results, you should always run Dojo from within any HTTP web server
>   (Apache, nginx, Tomcat, IIS, Jetty, etc.).

Lucian's remark about the missing http:, that isn't a problem:

> You may also load Dojo from a CDN. This is useful for quickly using Dojo, as it doesn't
>   require you to host your own copy of Dojo. You'll notice in many of our tutorials that we
>   show protocol-less URLs, e.g.  . This allows you to use Dojo within http and https
>   applications without adjusting the URL. For more information, check out the Dojo CDN 
>   tutorial

See: [Dojo Start](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/start/)

Comment: I was told I would really only need to run from a server if I was writing my own widgets. The things I am doing are not complicated, but as of right now I have to work in dojo 1.7 and without a server (work constraints). If it were up to me I'd do it all in jQuery and the server would be a moot point.

Comment: you don't have to use a local webserver to run dojo on a local machine !